# Error on bind_parm

Tags: php, sql, insert, addition, sql-delete

The code below is split into 3, are all in separate files, I keep getting error and not sure where I am going wrong because all the variable names match the database. is the formatting incorrect?

Please can someone help me, the error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I am doing edit, delete, add functions.

Delete:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','system');

$sql = "DELETE  FROM (id, staff_id, start_time,    
end_time) WHERE id=1";

 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->bind_param('iiss', $id, $staff_id, $start_time,    
$end_time);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Update:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','system');

$sql = "INSERT INTO roster(id, staffid, starttime, endtime) VALUES   
(?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $id, $staffid, $starttime, $endtime);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

edit:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','system');


$sql = "UPDATE roster(id, staff_id,starttime, endtime) WHERE id=1)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $id, $staffid, $starttime, $endtime);
$stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: You don't check if your connection succeeded, so add this after your connection: `if ($db->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $db->connect_errno . ') '
            . $db->connect_error);
}`

Comment: I presume your issue is the delete file. What are you even doing in there? Also your edit file? What?

Comment: connection is fine, i know it connects

Comment: `DELETE  FROM` - from what? `UPDATE` and `SET` what? `(?,?,?,?,?)` and 4 binds.

Comment: Nice Stealth edit `(?,?,?,?)` without marking as an edit. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28160705/3

Comment: delete the column selected, it was an error and u guys are just laughn at me. thanks

Comment: Nobody's laughing at you. We're wondering what you're trying to delete from and what you want to update. That's totally unclear and we don't know your table and column names; **you do**. Read up on those functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Plus, where are all those variables being assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are all wrong. Your `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements are completely incorrect. An `UPDATE` statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col = val, col2 = val2 WHERE col3 = val3
```

While your `DELETE` has to be structure like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE col1 = val1
```

And your issues with the `bind_param()` is because you aren't specifying any columns to bind to (like you do in your `INSERT` query)

---

Read up on those functions:

- DELETE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html
- UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Also to add he wants to insert 5 values into 4 columns  :D

Comment: ... `(?,?,?,?,?)` and 4 binds `bind_param("iiss", $id, $staffid, $starttime, $endtime)`

Comment: ^ scratch that. Stealth edit *now in progress...* http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28160705/3

Comment: like you have never made a mistake!! ridiculous comments

Comment: @user3552356 You'd be surprised as to why people downvote answers based on new code and not being marked as an edit. Don't pull stunts like that.

Comment: @user3552356 Example: **Edit:** *Sorry, I made a mistake, it should have read as....* rest of new code etc.

Comment: Another thing; from what's been posted, we don't even know if OP is even assigning those variables. *groan*